# Unable to import torchvision despite successful installation

Tags: python, dll, pytorch, torchvision

I am not able to import torchvision despite successful installation.

Environment OS : Windows

> runfile('C:/Users/kundan/Desktop/Computer_Vision/Computer_Vision_A_Z_Template_Folder/Module
> 2 - Object Detection/data/untitled1.py',
> wdir='C:/Users/kundan/Desktop/Computer_Vision/Computer_Vision_A_Z_Template_Folder/Module
> 2 - Object Detection/data') Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "C:\Users\kundan\Desktop\Computer_Vision\Computer_Vision_A_Z_Template_Folder\Module
> 2 - Object Detection\data\untitled1.py", line 8, in 
> import torchvision
>
> File
> "C:\Users\kundan.conda\envs\mynewflaskenv\lib\site-packages\torchvision_*init*_.py",
> line 1, in 
> from torchvision import models
>
> File
> "C:\Users\kundan.conda\envs\mynewflaskenv\lib\site-packages\torchvision\models_*init*_.py",
> line 11, in 
> from . import detection
>
> File
> "C:\Users\kundan.conda\envs\mynewflaskenv\lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\detection_*init*_.py",
> line 1, in 
> from .faster_rcnn import *
>
> File
> "C:\Users\kundan.conda\envs\mynewflaskenv\lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\detection\faster_rcnn.py",
> line 7, in 
> from torchvision.ops import misc as misc_nn_ops
>
> File
> "C:\Users\kundan.conda\envs\mynewflaskenv\lib\site-packages\torchvision\ops_*init*_.py",
> line 1, in 
> from .boxes import nms, box_iou
>
> File
> "C:\Users\kundan.conda\envs\mynewflaskenv\lib\site-packages\torchvision\ops\boxes.py",
> line 2, in 
> from torchvision import _C
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens with some python libraries.

This video can help you: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmvRF7koJ5E)

1 .Download msvcp71.dll and msvcr71.dll from the web.
2 .Save them to your C:\Windows\System32 folder.
3 .Save them to your C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder as well (if you have a 64-bit operating system).

Now try running your code file in Python .